# Angular Data-Binding Private Property Of Object

Tags: angular, angular6

This class has **private** properties and **getter** **setter** methods.

**Season.ts :**

```
export class Season {

  private _seasonId: number;
  private _name: string;  

  get seasonId(): number {
    return this._seasonId;
  }

  set seasonId(value: number) {
    this._seasonId = value;
  }

  get name(): string {
    return this._name;
  }

  set name(value: string) {
    this._name = value;
  }

}
```

And I have a component to show it:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-season',
  templateUrl: './season.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./season.component.css']
})
export class SeasonComponent implements OnInit {


  season: Season = new Season();
  seasons: Season[] = [];

 //....

 // There is some stuff to fill 'seasons' array 
  private addSeason(seasonForm: NgForm) {
    if (!this.isUpdateMode) {
      this.addNewMemberToSeasons();
    } else {
      this.editSeasonsMember();
    }
    this.seasonsChange.emit(this.seasons.slice());
    this.resetSeasonForm(seasonForm);
  }

  private editSeasonsMember() {
    const editIndex = this.seasons.findIndex((s) => s.seasonId === this.season.seasonId);
    this.seasons[editIndex] = Object.assign({}, this.season);
  }

  private addNewMemberToSeasons() {
    const clone = Object.assign({}, this.season);
    this.seasons.push(clone);
  }
 // ...
```

**HTML**

```
<li class="list-group-item ..." *ngFor="let season of seasons">
    <div>
      <h6 class="my-0">{{season.name}}</h6>
    </div>
    <span>
            <span class="btn-group-sm" role="group">
              <button type="button" class="btn-sm btn-outline-warning"
                      (click)="editSeason(season.name)">Edit</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn-sm btn-outline-danger"
                      (click)="deleteSeason(season.name)">Delete</button>
            </span>
          </span>
  </li>
```

After add new season to seasons array I can see new **blank** list-group-item with buttons in my template. But there is no `name` about the season. And the console is clear.
If I use interpolation binding like this:  `{{season._name}}` it works and I can see the name property on my template. But this time WebStorm is warning me :

```
ng: Identifier '_name' refers to a private member of 'Season'
```

**How can I render an object that has private properties, with interpolation binding?**

I am using Angular 6.

Here is the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jzwb5a).

---

Sorry, I hadn't added some important methods of `Component` for the sake of readability.I have updated question with methods. Actually, the problem was there:

```
const clone = Object.assign({}, this.season);
this.seasons.push(clone);
```

Thanks to user184994.

Comment: So you're saying `{{season.name}}` doesn't work? Are you able to reproduce in a StackBlitz?

Comment: I have never used StackBlitz but I will try. And yes `{{season.name}}` is not working.

Comment: In Typescript when a member is marked private, it cannot be accessed from outside of its containing class.

Comment: @Und3rTow Yep, the issue is that the `get` accessor doesn't appear to be working  in `{{season.name}}`

Comment: @user184994 I added the demo.

Comment: @MuhammedOzdogan When you do `Object.assign`, you will lose the accessors, so it will no longer have the `get` function

Comment: @user184994 indeed, that is because it is returning a private member

Comment: @Und3rTow That's pretty much always how a `get` accessor would work. The fact that the underlying variable is private is moot, it's being exposed by the `get` (although in this case the `get` is lost due to `Object.assign`)

Comment: @user184994 But I have to clone my object before adding to the array. How can I clone get functions?

Comment: Why do you need to clone it?

Comment: @user184994 Because I have inputs in the template and I bonded inputs with `this.season` So after adding new seasons to list, I have to clear form inputs like  ` seasonForm.reset();` If I do without cloning bounded object it affects array elements.

Comment: Do as @TamoDev has done, and create a constructor that allows you to create a new copy easily

Comment: @user184994 Thank you very much. I think I got the matter. Actually, the real `Season` class is bigger than the above. So if I do as @TamoDev answer then I have to write something like this   `  season: Season = new Season(null, null, null, null, null )  ` in order to initiate the season that bounded to the template, I think it's a little bit ugly. I don't have two constructors in the typescript. Do you recommend a cleaner way to clone the object with getter setters?

Comment: Instead of passing the properties individually, you could create a constructor that takes a`Season`, so `season = new Season(oldSeason)`, and do it that way? Does that make sense?

Comment: What about the context of the constructor? It becomes dirty work. I think I shouldn't have used getter setter :)

Comment: What do you mean by the context of the constructor? Surely you can just do `this.name = oldSeason.name; this.whatever = oldSeason.whatever`?

Comment: Some properties of the Season class not primitive, some of the custom objects and some of them custom object array.  So I can't do this `this.customObject = season.customObject` I have to clone them too. Otherwise, if the user gets an element from the array in order to update Season when the user changed somethings on the element it can affect other objects that in the array.